# Why should I insert a non-UI Windows.Forms component from the designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In C# (and Visual Basic) you can add several non-UI components (those that don't inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`) directly from the form designer. Examples of those components are `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

But what's the benefit from adding non-UI controls with the UI designer instead of instancing them directly from code? There's a rationale behind that?

Comment: InitializeComponent() has the code for the things that you have just dropped, if I understand you correctly

Comment: @brykneval I know where the designer declares and initializes the components, but I don't understand the benefit of using the designer for non-UI components.

Comment: You could check if for objects that implement `IDisposable`, whether the designer adds a `Dispose()` call in the `Disposing(bool disposing)`. Or do a find all references on the variable name and see if there is any code added (besides the obvious).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need design-time support and if you yourself will take care of writing standard code to initialize and dispose the component, then you don't need to drop component on designer.

Using non-UI components in designer has these benefits:

- Design-time support
- Standard code (for initialize and dispose)

**Design-Time Support**

One of the most powerful things that you have in windows forms is the ability to use designer to set Component properties.

Even though `Timer` is not a UI component, but you can set its properties like interval at design time. This applies to many other components like `BindingSource`, `ErrorProvider`, and etc that you can use very friendly property grid and type editors and type converters to configure properties at design time.

- When you want to configure dependent properties for other controls; for example by adding `BindingSource` to designer, it makes data binding very easy.
- When you need to use extender providers like `HelpProvider` and `Tooltip`, since they are related to other controls, it is very easy to configure them at design mode.
- When you need to configure properties like `DataSource` and `DataMember`, it is very friendly to use designer and use great property grid features.
- Components will add as class level fields, and you can make them public using deigner.
- When you need to use `Localizable` feature of `Form` for your components, it's completely available using designer.
- When you need to simply add or remove event handlers you can do it using property grid.

**Standard Code**

If you take a look at designer generated code you will see:

- Generated code for components that supports `ISupportInitialize` uses their  `BeginInit` and `EndInit`
- Generated code for components, pass `this.components` to constructor and then use it when `Dispose`

If you don't need design-time support and you write standard code for components, so it's completely OK to use theme in code.