# Best Practices: Add controls in Design-Time or Run-Time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

May be an stupid question, or too subjective, or 'it depends', but... are there any preferences or best practices on adding some controls in design time or runtime? In terms of portability, decoupling model from view, and this stuff, could it be relevant?

For example, I need to use a FolderBrowserDialog. Should be better to add it to the form in design mode or just declare it in runtime?

EDIT: Thanks all for your reply. In this particular case: I've created a button for the user to pick a folder. My idea is to use a FolderBrowserDialog. Should I declare the FoleBrowserDialog INSIDE the 'button clik' event or create it on design time embedding it in the form? For me, it's EASIER to create it in design time, as the properties will be easily accessible for all the form, but I think its more correct to declare it inside the event function, gather the path in a string, dispose the control, an return the value. Why? To use a FileBrowserDialog is a 'implementation detail' of the 'button click' event handler, irrelevant for the rest of the Form. Decoupling :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too broad.  The answer is most certainly "it depends".  Do you have a narrower example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Designer is a tool. Use it as needed, whenever it helps you do your job. But if you create controls and components at runtime, *don't forget to dispose them when they're no longer needed* (it happens automatically if you use the designer).

Comment: Designer is a tool which generate `.net` code based on the actions you executes in the designer. Open `YourForm.Designer.cs` file and compare the code generated by Designer and code you plan to use in your "run-time". Then you can decide by yourself what is a difference and which approach will be most preferred for you

Comment: it the form is not dynamic, so the controls will remain where they are and no controls will popup in any conditions than why do so much coding when the designer can do this for you ? Using the designer is not considered bad practice.

Comment: You can use code or use designer based on your requirement. There is nothing bad in using designer. It's really good tools that help you develop your application more rapid. But sometimes you may need to generate a UI dynamically using code. Take a look at this post: [Why should I insert a non-UI Windows.Forms component from the designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800751/why-should-i-insert-a-non-ui-windows-forms-component-from-the-designer)

Comment: Thanks all for your replies, specially the link provided by @RezaAghaei

Comment: @Luaan, good point, to remember me manually disposing

Comment: @Kaikus You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no difference between using the designer or defining the control variable in the code, because the designer also provides some equivalent C# code after dragging & dropping the control into your form. You can see this auto-generated code in the files with ***.Designer.cs** prefix and you may edit and change the auto-generated code 
**But** in some specific cases you may prefer to define your controls manually in the code.
for example:

1. Sometimes count, arrangement and configuration of the controls can be changed dynamically during run-time. for example, there is a config file beside your application and some changeable parameters in this config file determine count and properties of some controls in your GUI.
2. You may prefer to limit scope of definition of your control to a single function instead of allover the namespace or allover your form class.

Comment: Thanks! The scope of a non-UI control is an important thing to take in mind! I'll edit my question to reflect this point :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the designer is fine.  In the FolderBrowser example you gave I've done both in different projects.  Luaan has a good point about disposing manually created controls though.

Answer (score 1):

It is 'depends' indeed.

Normally I hate to use any form of UI designer tools (just my point of view and it is totally subjective).

I don't like when every single control in the form are defined as class level fields (and that is what will happen if I use the designer), such as some Labels that will never change a thing after initialized. In return, you cannot see the Label in the UI designer if you created them in runtime.

But sometimes when I am developing a new, small and shortage-of-time application, I would not be hesitated to take the benefit from the designer. (It is really fast if you could drag 'n drop controls, resizing them by just some mouse clicks)

I think the bottom line is you have to know what is happening between assigning controls by the designer and create them in runtime by yourself. After that, this question will be turned to a simple 'which monitor am I going to purchase', you can use whatever tool/method you want, according to your requirements.