# How to get message over the text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, message

I have  interface with  textbox which has  list of commands, and I want to show this list when the user hover the mouse on textbox.

I can put message  with label, but seems it is not the best way, looks not really good

Here is how I want get it and and same with labels:

[image]

Maybe you can advice me some better way to show it, also very interesting

Comment: You can use a [ToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he23h308(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Reza Aghaei so this is the answer I guess

Comment: Yes that's the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) had already said to use a [ToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he23h308(v=vs.110).aspx). Here's how you can do it:

Creating and returning the list:

```
static List<string> PopulateList()
{
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    mylist.Add("insert (a1) to get this");
    mylist.Add("insert (a2) to get this");
    mylist.Add("insert (a3) to get this");
    mylist.Add("insert (a4) to get this");
    ...
    ...
    return mylist;
}
```

Displaying the Tooltip on the `Enter` event of the TextBox:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tooltiptext = "";
    List<string> mylist = PopulateList();
    foreach (string listitem in mylist)
    {
        tooltiptext += listitem + "\n";
    }
    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
    tt.Show(tooltiptext, textBox1, 2000);
}
```

***Result:***

[image: tooltip]

Comment: Usually you don't need more than one instance of `ToolTip`. Currently you created multiple instance of the `ToolTip` in the `Enter` event of control which is not a good idea. Also when you want to create a `ToolTip` in code, you should not forget to `Dispose` it. You can simply Create the `ToolTip` at design-time. Take a look at [Why should I insert a non-UI Windows.Forms component from the designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800751/why-should-i-insert-a-non-ui-windows-forms-component-from-the-designer)