# When should we implement a constructor with the IContainer parameter for a Component?

Tags: c#, winforms, components, dispose, idisposable

Let's assume I have a WinForms Component.
It can be a class based on the [System.ComponentModel.Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component) or [System.Windows.Forms.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control) class (actually `Control` inherits `Component`).

My Component may use other .NET classes we should dispose correctly - Pens, Brushes, ContextMenuStrips and the like. I dispose them as expected in an implementation of the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method according to the well-known [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) pattern.

I wonder, when I must add a special constructor accepting an [IConatiner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icontainer) parameter so the Form Designer will register an instance of my Component for automatic resource disposal during the Form shutdown:

```c#
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    ...
    this.contextMenuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

I analyzed the source code of the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method of some WinForms Component trying to find an answer, but the situation is still not clear.
For example, the `ContextMenuStrip` Component has such a constructor, but `DataGridView` doesn't - though both has enough objects they dispose in their `Dispose(bool disposing)` implementations.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: That's a Designer requirement. Do you want your Component to show up in the Designer's Tray area or do you want to parent it to a Form? A ContextMenuStrip (as you mentioned it), is not usually parented to a Form, so it's handled as a Component and provides a constructor for this. When the Component is disposed of, the overridden `Dispose(disposing)` method is called, which in turn calls the `Dispose()` methods of all disposable objects down the inheritance chain (to ToolStripDropDown -> ToolStrip -> Control). If you add a Component to the Project, all this is already pre-built.

Comment: If you create, e.g., a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` Component in code, you should check whether the `components` object is `null` and create it if it is, then build the Timer using the Constructor that accepts an `IContainer` object. If you don't, then you have to dispose of the Timer explicitly when the Form closes. If you don't, the `TimerNativeWindow` calls `KillTimer()` only when it's itself finalized. It may be too late; the Timer's `Dispose(false)` method is called when the application closes: the Timer keeps running...

Comment: @Jimi, even if a Component does not implement the IContainer constructor, it is still shown in the Designer's Tray area.

Comment: Yes it will be visible in tray. That constructor just brings design-time support for code generation of adding the component to components collection of the form.

Comment: *That's a Designer requirement*: when you create a new Component using the Component Template, all the (very few) required parts are added to the class. Then the Designer can add the Component to the IContainer object. If an IContainer object doesn't exist yet, it's created. This allows Components - which clearly are not added to any `Controls` collection - to be disposed of when the Form is disposed. If a Component is not automatically added to the IContainer, it's `Dispose()` method is never called. Only the Finalizer will call `Dispose(false)`. Unmanaged Resources are not released. [...]

Comment: [...] If still *active* (a Timer Component that keeps on ticking), it's never disposed. When Components or Controls are created at run-time, if not *manually* added to the `components` Container or the `Controls` collection of an existing Control, their `Dispose()` method needs to be called explicitly, to avoid memory and resources leaks. -- In normal conditions, when a non-modal Form is closed, all Controls in the `Controls` containers hierarchy are disposed of and the Form's `Dispose(disposing)` override take care of the `components` container. It's a quite straightforward procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a component author, as a best practice, my advice is implementing constructor overload which accepts `IContainer`, because when a component has such constructor, when developer drops an instance of the component on the design surface, the designer generates a piece of code which cares about dispose of the component.

- **Is your component available in ToolBox?**

  For components which are accessible through toolbox, if the user drops the component on designer, then they should not be concerned about disposing of the component. All the standard components follow this pattern and users are never concerned about dispose of the controls and component which they create through designer, so it's component author's responsibility to care about design-time support.
- **Do you have anything to dispose in your component?**

  If you don't have anything to dispose, then this overload is not that important, but if you have anything to dispose, then you should care about dispose. As mentioned in the previous bullet point, since users may drop your component on designer and count on designer to dispose them then it's your responsibility to provide that method so designer generated the dispose code. Otherwise, the component will not be disposed which results in memory/handle leak.

**As a component user**

As a component user, if you create the component in code (and not dropping it at design-time) you are responsible to take care of disposing the component when you no more need it. You may find this post useful: [Why should I insert a non-UI Windows.Forms component from the designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32800751/3110834)

If you drop a component from toolbox, then you don't need to worry about its disposal. All the *standard components* generate a code o dispose the component on dispose of the form.

### How the designer generated code handles dispose of the components?

For the components which have a constructor which accepts `IContainer`, when you drop them on design surface, the designer generates a code to create a `components` collection and add the component to that collection, then disposes the collection (including all its component) when the form disposes.

Looking into the the following piece of designer-generated code:

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (disposing && (components != null))
   {
       components.Dispose();
   }
   base.Dispose(disposing);
}

InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    ...
    ...
    this.myComponent = new MyComponent(this.components);
    ...
    ...
}
```

And [Dispose method of Container](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Container.cs,128) class:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
        lock (syncObj) {
            while (siteCount > 0) {
                ISite site = sites[--siteCount];
                site.Component.Site = null;
                site.Component.Dispose();
            }
            sites = null;
            components = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You see when your form is disposed, it will dispose all the components that it finds in the container.

Comment: Consider the following situation. The developer places a Component implementing `Dispose(bool disposing)` in the Designer's Tray area, and this instance is not registered in the form's components collection. What happens with this Component object when the user closes the form? Will it lead to serious resource leak problems, especially if the user will open this form over and over again during the application life cycle?

Comment: Yes,  it leads into handle/memory leak. If the component required to be disposed, but doesn't have a constructor which accepts `IContainer`, then when the user drops it on design surface, it will not be added to the components collection and as a result it wont dispose on disposal of form.

Comment: Users of your component should not care about disposing of the component if you allow them to drop it on designer. They expect you handle the dispose. But for the classes which are not available in toolbox, users are responsible for caring about dispose.

Comment: as I understand, all the Component instances will be eventually GC'ed. However, they will prevent the host form from being destroyed properly, and all those form objects will remain in the memory until the GC operation, right?

Comment: **eventually** <- it may be too late. You need to dispose them as soon as you don't need them.

Comment: I rephrased the answer a bit, hope it makes the things clearer. Short answer is: For a component which is available in toolbox and has something to dispose, as a best practice you should have a constructor overload which accepts `IContainer`. It's a design-time support, which allows the designer to generate a piece of code to care about dispose of the component. Otherwise, the users should care about dispose of the component themselves, which is not gonna happen, because they never dispose anything which add through designer. So it's your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to create the extra constructor with the IContainer. If you omit this, then you have to add the Control to the IContainer yourself.

```
public void MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    this.components.Add(this.MyUserControl);
}
```

If you don't add this to this.components, you have to explicitly Dispose MyUserControl.
Extra problem: if no one uses this.components, then this.components will still be null.

So all in all, it is way less work to add the extra constructor whenever you create a control that must be Disposed. After all, it is a one-liner.

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    ...
}

public MyUserControl(IContainer container) : this()
{
    container?.Add(this);
}
```

The nice thing is, that visual studio designer recognizes this constructor and will use it. It will even create the Container for you.

Comment: There's no point in adding a Control (a visual Component that inherits from Control) to the `IContainer` object: Controls already dispose all child Controls in their `Controls` collection when `Dispose()` is called. It's a cascading effect. Components, on the other hand, are not Controls so they're not part of this collection, that's why they're added to a different container that is disposed of when the Parent Container is disposed. Other Controls that don't need *parenting* and don't have a visual (as a ContextMenuStrip), are added to the Designer's Tray and handled as Components.

Comment: You are right. According to the description [Control.Dispose(bool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dispose?view=net-5.0) "Releases the unmanaged resources used by the Control and its child controls and optionally releases the managed resources." Alas it doesn't say whether the managed resources of the child controls will be released, but if I look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9884211b7ff61817), `Dispose()` of every child control is called

Comment: Exactly. When a Control is disposed, it calls `Dispose()` on all Controls that are part of its `Controls` collection and child Controls, as a consequence, do the same with their `Controls` collection. But Components are not part of this collection, that's where the `components` collection comes into play, with a similar (the same, in practice) effect.